# Gromov-Hausdorff-Prokhorov distance reference

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request, hausdorff-distance, gromov-hausdorff-limit

I have been interested as of late in a notion which I discovered is called the Gromov-Hausdorff-Prokhorov distance, and have been looking for reading material on the subject.

Does any one know of relatively accessible references to the subject? I have so far only found articles in arXiv on the subject, and don't know their validity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best introductory account I know of is Chapter 7 on pp. 241-270 (see also the additional material in Chapter 8 on pp. 271-306) in the following book:

Dmitri Jurjewitsch Burago, Yuri Dmitrievich Burago, and Sergei Vladimirovitsch Ivanov, [**A Course in Metric Geometry**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821821296), Graduate Studies in Mathematics #33, American Mathematical Society, 2001, xiv + 415 pages.

> [table of contents, preface, bibliography, index](https://www.ams.org/books/gsm/033/gsm033-endmatter.pdf)
>
> [*extensive errata list*](https://www.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Esvivanov/papers/bbi-errata.pdf)

Comment: I think the aforementioned book only includes the Gromov--Hausdorff distance and not the Gromov--Hausdorff--Prokhorov.